# For Loops + Functions not storing data correctly?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to use a For Loop to store data (counting crossovers/crossunders) into an array so i can cut out alot of coding

Here is a simplified version of my script, if anyone could help me that would be great

Its a script that has 2 options for a Moving Average(EMA, VWMA) and 3 lengths
What it should do is count the times the chosen MA has crossed the closing price, for each length
But what i think its doing is counting all the crosses for each length and combining them?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Cross Counting", overlay = true)

//MA Functions
f_EMA(length) =>
    EMA = ta.ema(close, length)

f_VWMA(length) =>
    VWMA = ta.sma(close * volume, length) / ta.sma(volume, length)

f_crossovercount(ma, slowma) =>
    var crosscount = 0
    if ta.crossover(ma, slowma)
        crosscount := crosscount + 1
    if ta.crossunder(ma, slowma)
        crosscount := crosscount + 1
    crosscount

fastma = input.string("Disabled", title="Fast MA", options=["Disabled", "EMA", "VWMA"])
Length1 = input(10, title="Length 1")
Length2 = input(10, title="Length 2")
Length3 = input(10, title="Length 3")

ma1 = fastma == "EMA" ? f_EMA(Length1) : fastma == "VWMA" ? f_VWMA(Length1) : na
ma2 = fastma == "EMA" ? f_EMA(Length2) : fastma == "VWMA" ? f_VWMA(Length2) : na
ma3 = fastma == "EMA" ? f_EMA(Length3) : fastma == "VWMA" ? f_VWMA(Length3) : na

float[] fastMAArray = array.new_float(3)
float[] countedArray = array.new_float(3)

array.set(fastMAArray, 0, ma1)
array.set(fastMAArray, 1, ma2)
array.set(fastMAArray, 2, ma3)

for i = 0 to array.size(fastMAArray) - 1
    array.set(countedArray, i, f_crossovercount(array.get(fastMAArray, i), close))
```